# Helm chart - long and boring deployment

Tags: performance, kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have huge application with many many microservices, which developed by different teams.
There is chart which includes tens of subcharts.

Deployment of this chart takes 10 min (only render all values) and start deployment.
As I mentioned there are different teams which have different style when writing helm charts.

So my questions - are there any useful helm performance tools which could show "problematic" places? For example point out that charts have many tpl function calls, which leads to slowness...

Comment: I've never seen Helm itself be the source of slowness.  If you create a StatefulSet creates a PersistentVolumeClaim needs your cloud provider to create a PersistentVolume, and then there's a minute-long database initialization, and then a post-install hook loads seed data, _that_ can take a while, but that's not the Helm code itself and that's going to be very hard to determine by static analysis.

Comment: Yep, I clearly understand that helm code most probably is not related. I am trying to identify problematic place within my chart. For example too much tpl functions calls, or to much pvc, or some other things that I could improv within my chart. 

That is why I thought that there might be some soft, kind of profiler, which could scan my charts and give some report.

Comment: @liotur, could you attach your helm code to the question?